# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: java, windows, apache, maven

I get the following error when I type the command `mvn --version`:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890116/apache-maven-install-mvn-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-a) but still I am unable to get the work done.

when I type this command `echo %M2_HOME%` I get path printed as `D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4`

when I type 'echo %M2%' I get the path printed as `D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin`

Environment : `Windows XP`

Comment: The bin folder needs to be set on your `%PATH%` environment variable. The other variables are irrelevant in order to execute the batch from the shell. Have a look at `%PATH%`

Comment: make sure to relanuch your cmd window after changing path

Comment: For me it was not working since I was editing Path variable in "User variable" and adding it under "System variable" made it work. Hope it helps.

Comment: None of mentioned solutions helped me. It turns out that I had to move modify `PATH` variable and move %JAVA_HOME%\bin before %M2_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure you have your maven bin directory in the path and the JAVA_HOME property set

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is not required in order to get `mvn --version` to run. It is required for compilation, but that's later.

Comment: yes maven bin directory is there in the path specified. also i agree with Andreas_D :)

Comment: @kirschmichel I have setup all(JAVA_HOME, M2, M2_HOME)and updated in path, but still I have getting same error 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or....

Answer (score 39):

On my Windows 7 machine I have the following environment variables:

- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
- M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.0.3

On my `PATH` variable, I have (among others) the following:

- %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin

I tried doing what you've done with `%M2%` having the nested `%M2_HOME%` and it also works.

Comment: nicely done. Do remember to check whether you are using appropriate java version e.g. jdk 1.8 and JAVA_HOME is updated to use appropriate jdk if you have multiple installed.

Comment: Whole time I was typing **maven -version**,instead of **mvn -version** :P

Answer (score 12):

Add maven directory `/bin` to System variables under the name `Path`.

To check this, you can `echo %PATH%`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the 'java' is not recognized in cmd and 'mvn' is not recognized in cmd and 'JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.'

I assumed that I had maven in my computer, but I was wrong.  I must have done with my previous downloaded maven.  So, I download maven again.  I checked my java location, too.  Then, 'mvn' is recognized, but JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.  When I put the full location of maven, my terminal recognized mvn command.  Then, I could do the mvn clean install command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eBFM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB05E.png)
These are my local computer Environment Variables.  Please look at Path in User variables for my local computer.  This Path is for java.  Then, look at PATH in System variable.  This PATH is for maven.  Last, please look at System variables.  JAVA_HOME Value does not end with bin.  I put jre instead of bin or nothing as someone wrote on the internet.  That person does not why this way works, though.  M2 Value is copied from the internet suggestion.  M2_HOME is the location of maven in my local computer.