# mvn is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: maven

I am trying to launch maven project from command line but when i try using mvn --version
or any other maven command it comes up with below error message

`mvn is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: Great. so install mvn :P

Comment: Where is maven installed?  Does PATH contain maven bin folder?

Comment: Maven is installed in my drive other than C and yes PATH contains maven bin folder

Comment: you can refer this answer :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890116/apache-maven-install-mvn-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-a][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890116/apache-maven-install-mvn-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-a

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not installed in your OS. Please follow instructions from the following link
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation

Comment: Maven is installed, i have set the environment variables properly too

Comment: I have tried all the solutions given on stackoverflow tried moving user variables to system variable also changed MAVE_HOME to M2_HOME Nothing is working for me.I am using windows 7 Somebody please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you installed Maven to `D:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.3` ...
then your system environment PATH needs to contain the string
    `D:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin`
which should be separated from the other path entries using the path separator: `;`

And, BTW, you don't need to set `MAVEN_HOME` or `M2_HOME`.
On my win7 system, I just put Maven's bin-folder on the path and set up a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable that points to an installation folder of a JDK ( e.g. `D:\tools\jdk7u15` ), that's all.

Comment: The issue was fixed with a little trick..Actually i had installed some differnt version of jdk jre on my machine then also installed maven after that.But after sometime i found those jdk jre are not the correct on for my project so i deleted them,but i didn't removed environment variables of maven.After installation of newer jdk jre i was unable to use maven inside that so it was just a hit and try to removed environment variable of maven completly and add them again so it has luckily worked for me.. but i still didn't understand the logic behind that.

Answer (score 0):

just change M2 AND M2_HOME from user variables into system variables in advanced settings. it worked well with me.