# maven is not recognized even after setting the environment variable

Tags: maven, installation

I have installing maven by extracting it from a zip folder and extracted it directly to c drive.i then copied its path and then made M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME in  system variables,copied the path there,and changed the path in both the user and system variables with the exact process but it is still not recognized as an internal or external batch file

please help me solve it.

Comment: Please make sure that your `PATH` variable points to mavens `bin` directory

Comment: Do not use M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME only add the bin directory into the PATH variable. that's it...and not to forget use JAVA_HOME...

Comment: This is already resolved here
Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890116/apache-maven-install-mvn-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-a?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system after update path variable

> %M2_HOME%\bin